# Evernote Python API - How to get a list of tags for a note?

Tags: python, api, evernote

This is my code for listing notebooks and their notes. I'm now trying to list the tags associated with each note. Can someone help? Thanks.

```
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
from evernote.edam.notestore import NoteStore

dev_token = "dev_token"
client = EvernoteClient(token=dev_token)
userStore = client.get_user_store()

user = userStore.getUser()
print
print user.username
print

noteStore = client.get_note_store()
notebooks = noteStore.listNotebooks()

for n in notebooks:
   print "Notebook = " + n.name + " GUID = " + n.guid

   filter = NoteStore.NoteFilter()
   filter.ascending = False
   filter.notebookGuid=n.guid

   spec = NoteStore.NotesMetadataResultSpec()
   spec.includeTitle = True
   spec.includeNotebookGuid = True
   spec.includeTagGuids = True

   ourNoteList = noteStore.findNotesMetadata(filter, 0, 25, spec)
   for note in ourNoteList.notes:
      print "%s :: %s" % (note.title, note.guid)
   print
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask]
(http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to improve your question with sufficient information to describe and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you call [NoteStore#findNotesMetadata](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata) with `spec.includeTagGuids = True`, the returned [NoteMetadata](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteMetadata) will contain a list of tag GUIDs associated with the notes.

```
spec = NoteStore.NotesMetadataResultSpec()
spec.includeTagGuids = True

notesMetadataList = noteStore.findNotesMetadata(filter, 0, 25, spec)
for noteMetadata in notesMetadataList.notes:
   for tagGuid in noteMetadata.tagGuids
       tag = noteStore.getTag(tagGuid)
```

or, if you just want names of tags, you could use [NoteStore#getNoteTagNames](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNoteTagNames).

```
notesMetadataList = noteStore.findNotesMetadata(filter, 0, 25, spec)
for noteMetadata in notesMetadataList.notes:
   tagNames = noteStore.getNoteTagNames(noteMetadata.guid)
```

But it would be better to call [NoteStore#listTags](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_listTags) at first and create a dictionary from tag guids to tag so that you don't have to call [NoteStore#getTag](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getTag) every time in the loop.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. Got it working in the sandbox environment. I then got a developer token for production and now it raises a bunch of exceptions. Do you know if there's anything different I need to do when pushing code over using production tokens?

Comment: Figured it out. Have to use 'client = EvernoteClient(token=dev_token, sandbox = False)'